# Understanding the behavior of constructors in move, copy, assign semantics

Tags: c++, constructor, semantics

Here is a minimal program which outputs C-tors & D-tors, also Move/Copy operations.

What is intriguing to me is that there is just one C-tor in output, despite there is three entities which are destroyed at the end of the scope (D-tors displayed).

So why there is just one C-tor displayed ? and how can we handle it (display them), or if there is a misunderstanding from my part, what should we know about that.

```
#include <iostream>

class Subject{

public:

    Subject(){
       std::cout<<"Default C-tor"<<std::endl;

    }
    Subject(int data):mdata(data){
        std::cout<<"C-tor"<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual~Subject(){

        std::cout<<"D-tor"<<std::endl;
    }


    Subject(Subject const& subject): mdata(subject.mdata){
         std::cout<<"Object copied"<<std::endl;
   }

    Subject& operator=(Subject const& subject){
          if(this != &subject){
              mdata=subject.mdata;
         std::cout<<"Object copied"<<std::endl;
          }
          return *this;
    }

        Subject(Subject const&& subject): mdata(std::move(subject.mdata)){
         std::cout<<"Object moved"<<std::endl;
   }

    Subject& operator=(Subject const&& subject){
          if(this != &subject){
              mdata=std::move(subject.mdata);
         std::cout<<"Object moved"<<std::endl;
          }
          return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Subject const& subject){

        out<<subject.mdata<<std::endl;

        return out;
     }

protected:
    int mdata;

};

int main()
{
   Subject subject{42};

   Subject copySubject{subject};

   Subject moveSubject = std::move(subject);

    return 0;
}
```

Noting that if i declare the `copySubject` and the `moveSubject` like :

```
   Subject copySubject{};

   Subject moveSubject{};
```

It will work by calling the Default Constructor.

Comment: The move constructor, and move assignment should take `&&`, *not* `const &&`.

Answer (score 1):

> So why there is just one C-tor displayed ?

Because you used the converting int constructor once, when you direct initialised here:

> ```
> Subject subject{42};
> ```

---

> despite there is three entities which are destroyed

The other two objects were created using the copy constructor and move constructor respectively. Note how neither of these  constructors displays "C-tor".

You've defined three variables, so it should hardly be surprising that three objects were created and destroyed.

---

P.S. Your move assignment and constructor don't actually move the member because you used a const reference as argument.